# sonarqube unit tests to ignore rule that a variable must be private and have accessory methods

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, junit, sonarqube

Can you get sonarqube to ignore that a variable must be private and have accessory method in unit tests? it seems to be a bit redundant when it comes to units test because they're stand alone and don't need to be access the values outside of the test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That rule doesn't generally run on unit tests, so there's likely something odd with your project configuration. Make sure your unit tests aren't being picked up as source files.

OTOH, if you want your tests evaluated as though they were source files: run "normal" rules on them, but not all rules, then [Exclusions](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreIssues) are your best bet.

Comment: Hi Ann I did have my tests under the source folder as the project is a set of tests are basically used for UI tests using the selenium webDriver for a cloud system we develop on . I moved them to a test folder and added "sonar.tests" to my  sonar-project-properties file. The problem is that now the tests are not being evaluated because they're not under the source file. Any recommendations?

Comment: Thanks Ann I think this will work for me but I think I will need to update my the version of the sonar server first before I can use this setting I am currently running 3.5.1 thank you for your help